# Fastest server in C

Tags: c

I am working on a server written in C and I am wondering what's the most efficient way to deal with multiple request concurrently.

Should I use a new thread for each request received ? Should I fork my server when there's too many requests ?

Comment: Take a look at epoll

Comment: Use threads to full capacity of CPU and make a queue.

Comment: Look at the source code for servers such as nginx and Apache.